# PayPal Payment Option Not Shown in Front End If Base Currency Indian Rupee

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, currency

My site run in India, I have PayPal account for only international customers,

not Indian customer (Not Domestic, only international) and integrated with

Magento 1.9.2.3, after the integration my PayPal payment not shown In the front end.

[image]

> Base Currency INR

```
Supposed changed base currency to us dollar, it's working,
```

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PayPal doesn't support INR currency. [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/currency_codes/) for PayPal supported currencies. But INR support will be available in future, until that you will need to use other than USD for receiving payments and withdraw PayPal account balance to local bank account.